# Why does jsonb use more space for storing integers?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, json, array

I did some small tests to try these data types, found some puzzling results.

**Summary:**

jsonb uses more space for integers than strings:

```
select pg_column_size('{"a":"1"}'::jsonb) as json_size
```

18

```
select pg_column_size('{"a":1}'::jsonb) as json_size
```

28

Why does the size of jsonb inflate when using integers?

---

**Long version:**

I was originally interested in using an array of integers, here are those tests. In each pair of comma separated numbers, first corresponds to `json_size` (bytes), second number is `array_size` (bytes).

```
select pg_column_size('[]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

8,16

```
select pg_column_size('[1]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[1]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

20,26

Check if jsonb actually stores integers as plain text; if so then this next one should use 4 bytes more for jsonb:

```
select pg_column_size('[12345]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[12345]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

22,26

Strange, it uses 2 bytes more, no idea what that means. Try some more practical and realistic data now:

```
select pg_column_size('[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[123,234,345,456,567,678,789,890]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

**104,40**

What happened to jsonb here? What caused it to inflate? Maybe if I use smaller numbers that have less characters...

```
select pg_column_size('[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

104,40

Nope. What about strings?

```
select pg_column_size('["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]'::jsonb) as json_size, 
       pg_column_size(array[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]::smallint[]) as array_size
```

48,40

It seems that jsonb likes strings and not integers.

I quickly made it a rule of thumb that I should only use strings in jsonb and use native integers or arrays for numeric data, but I don't know if this rule is misguided or why this anomaly occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. JSON doesn't have a concept of an integer, only a "number". [From the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)

> When converting textual JSON input into jsonb, the primitive types described by RFC 7159 are effectively mapped onto native PostgreSQL types, as shown in Table 8-23.

That table shows a JSON "number" is mapped to a numeric. The max precision on numeric is

> up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point

However, I don't think it actually stores that. It does store a numeric of [some sort](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/1d25779284fe1ba08ecd57e647292a9deb241376/src/backend/utils/adt/jsonb.c#L774). The [numeric source is quite frankly kind of difficult to follow.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/9a34123bc315e55b33038464422ef1cd2b67dab2/src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c)

Using an array of smallint is clearly better if it fits your workload. It has less wasted space for packing, and less wasted space for the data itself. `smallint[]` however

- Does not support the same range of numbers.
- Does not support embedding different types.
- Does not support any precision at all.
- Does not exchange well with web-clients.

Comment: When you need to exchange, *then* you convert to JSON. That was the original *purpose* of JSON. You keep things nice, tidy and *native* database-side, and convert to JSON when talking to (a part of) the rest of the world.

Comment: That makes sense to have one datatype support all numerics, albeit excessively wasteful to use 12 bytes for simple integers. Perhaps beyond the scope of this question: I wonder why PostgreSQL does this instead of using integers when appropriate? If not for this "issue", I wouldn't have this indecision of whether I should continue switching to jsonb or go back to using a table with many nullable columns (currently leaning towards nullable columns).

Comment: @DavidTan nah, just think about it: PostgreSQL would have to have a complex method of internal promotion and index-rewrites. Consider `UPDATE foo SET json = $${"number": $var}$$;` where `foo.json->>"number"` is indexed. The `UPDATE` would have to lock the whole table, to check if `foo.json->>"number"` needed internal promotion from interger to something else, and then possibly rewrite the whole table and the index if that was the case. That wouldn't scale, at all.

Comment: Arrays in Postgres have 24 bytes of overhead, if you just serialized your []short as a bytea and cast it back to short, you'd save a lot of space unless your arrays are very large, on average. That would be difficult to query though.